# How do I receive Tin Can API statements?

Tags: java, moodle, tin-can-api

I have a source which emits Tin Can API statements and where I can provide endpoint where to send these statements (it's a plugin for moodle).

I want to write a simple Java server which will be able to receive these statements. Authentication is not required now. Just receive and print them out, like http://tincanapi.com/public-lrs/ does.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all you need is to handle POST-queries.

The tincanapi.com in its tech overview gives the following [example](http://tincanapi.com/tech-overview/#pt5) on how to send statement to LRS. Basically it's just a POST-query containing JSON representation of statement. So all you need is to write server which processes such queries.

The only not obvious pitfall that url which is used by your POST queries processing must end with '/statements'. And while specifying the endpoint for different clients you must omit this '/statements' part.